# Changing ggplot image size in flexdashboard

Tags: r-markdown, flexdashboard

In flexdashboard,
if you use

`vertical_layout: fill`

then the image is stretched to entire screen

If you use

`vertical_layout: scroll`

then the image is shown at some other (predetermined?) size

Is that possible to change the image size in both cases?

Code example is below:

````
## ...

### Plot

    ```{r}
    ggplot(diamonds) + geom_point(aes(carat, price)) 
    ```
````

Comment: ```fig.height + fig.weight``` like in the r-markdown

Comment: I tried replacing  my current chunk options `{r}` with `{r  fig.height ="100%", fig.weight="100%"}` and it crashed. I tried also using `out.width="100%"`.   (Error in *: non-numeric argument to binary operator)

Comment: Use not percents, f.e. ```fig.width = 5, fig.height = 10``` lol, i wrote fig.weight))) sorry